# External class handler interacting with UI

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am currently working on a class that will communicate with an external device through the `SerialPort` class, but I need to update the UI according to the messages the device send back.

I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace LearningSteps
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Comm.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public class Teste
    {
        private SerialPort _myPort;

        public Teste(SerialPort P) { _myPort = P; }

        public void Funcao(SerialDataReceivedEventHandler H)
        {
            _myPort.DataReceived += H;
            byte[] vetor = new byte[] { 0x24, 0x24, 0xCF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x25, 0x33, 0x7E };
            _myPort.Write(vetor, 0, 9);
        }
    }

    public partial class Comm : Window
    {
        SerialPort port;
        Teste T;

        public delegate void AtualizaCallBack(string message);
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

        public Comm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            port = new SerialPort("COM5",115200,Parity.None,8,StopBits.One);
            port.RtsEnable = false;
            port.DtrEnable = false;
            port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            port.NewLine = "~";
            port.Open();
            T = new Teste(port);

        }

        private void Recebido(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            String indata = sp.ReadExisting();

            my_label.Dispatcher.Invoke(new AtualizaCallBack(this.atualiza),new object[]{indata});

        }

        private void bt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            T.Funcao(Recebido);
        }

        private void atualiza(string s)
        {
            byte[] vet = encoding.GetBytes(s);
            my_label.Content = BitConverter.ToString(vet);
        }

    }
}
```

I get an error when I try to compile, which I think is because I'm trying to send an internal `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` as argument. But I don't know how I could use `T.Funcao` and update my UI otherwise.

The error says:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Window.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor type 'LearningSteps.Comm' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: My bad, I'm updating the question with the error description now.

Comment: That's not a compiler error, it is a runtime exception. Is there an inner exception? This looks like a XAML parse exception that has been thrown because of an exception in your constructor.

Comment: I didn't change anything in the XAML. In the older version I was using the `port.Write` method directly in the `bt_click`. Now I introduced the new class which is supposed to interface with my device.

Comment: Again, is there an inner exception? All useful information about the error is being swallowed by the `XamlParseException` so, unless there is an inner exception (which I am guessing there is), the error message is pretty useless.

Comment: Ok, this is very very weird. I reverted all the changes I made, and now the very same code that was working yesterday gives me the same error.

Comment: No, there is not, Ant P

Comment: Well the exception you've provided is certainly not the root exception. Can you debug and step through the constructor for `Conn` to find out where the exception occurs and what the *real* exception is?

Comment: Ok, Ant. Thx a lot for the step by step debug idea. What happened is that the virtual COM port of the device was changed and I didn't fix the code. I fixed it and now the old code worked, gonna retest this new version now.